# Aliexpress API - How to bind user on my website with Aliexpress orders?

Tags: javascript, api

All aliexpress cash back websites, automatically get user order after each purchase. How they do that?

Via API i can get all my affiliate orders (orders which makes after visit my generated URL) and I can get list of them using API response:

http://gw.api.alibaba.com/openapi/param2/2/portals.open/api.getCompletedOrders/[my_app_id]?appSignature=[my_app_signature]&startDate=2017-04-01&endDate=2017-04-24&liveOrderStatus=pay

and get:

```
{
    "result": {
        "totalResults": "-",
        "orders": [{
            "orderTime": "04-23-2017 00:20",
            "orderNumber": 83426736718999,
            "product": "Humor Bear Boys Clothing Sets Brand Boys Clothes 2017 Summer Fashion Style T-Shirts+Stripe Pant 2PCS Boys Clothes",
            "orderStatus": "Completed Payments",
            "commissionRate": "8.0%",
            "paymentAmount": "8.25",
            "estimatedCommission": "0.66",
            "finalPaymentAmount": "0.00",
            "commission": "0.00",
            "extraParams": "{}",
            "trackingId": "smartbuy",
            "pid": "888445371"
        }]
    },
    "errorCode": 20010000
}
```

but I don't know which user make this order. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe they use the orderTime?